# NSImageView Center?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, animation

I am trying to make Pong for Mac. For the ball bounce code, I am trying to access the ball's center. The ball is a NSImageView. For iOS programming, I can just access a UIImageView's center by calling

```
ball.center = ...;
```

How can I do this with an NSImageView. Sorry if this is dumb, I'm new to Cocoa programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a simple category like:

```
- (void)ps_setCenter:(NSPoint)center;
{
    [self setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(center.x - (self.frame.size.width * 0.5f),
                                     center.y - (self.frame.size.height * 0.5f))];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: Jack K: If it's what You needed You should set this answer "Accept answer".